# pyqt - Include NoneType in Validator?

Tags: python, pyqt, nonetype, qvalidator

I am adding a double validator for a qlineedit widget. But in reality the line might be empty, i.e. data is of NoneType. However in this case I don't want the validator to pop up a warning saying for example:

please type in values between 0.000 to 10000.000

Is there any way to add NoneType as an excluding instance when adding Validator?

Thanks very much!

Comment: What method are you calling that returns `None`? If the line-edit is empty, its `text()` method will return an empty string.

Comment: I used text() indeed but immediately I put it into validator: self.validator.validate( self.text() )